# What effect do the orange, green and blue arrows have on B-Spec drivers?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

What effect do the orange, green and blue arrows have on B-Spec drivers?

For example, is it better to use a driver at level 25 with a blue arrow or a driver at level 30 with an orange arrow?

Answer (score 1):

The arrows indicate the driver's current performance.

You know how in sports, a player or driver can be "on form"?

This arrow indicates the driver's form. The upward blue arrow indicated "top form", the downward orange arrow is "off form" and the green arrow is "on form"

basically, if your driver has a blue arrow, he will drive better than normal, while orange will make them perform more poorly.